# Decode javascript image URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetnuke

While working in Visual studio MVC3 i got a problem with a image url.

I am using some jquery and i get the image url like this:

```
var url = $(this).attr("src");
image = decodeURI(url);
```

the url i get back is the `UserContent%C3%BErgers%EF%BF%BD102145860-Koala.jpg`

When i use the javascript alert function it show the url like it should be:`\UserContent\fergers\102145860-Koala.jpg`

Anyone got a suggestion? The`decodeURI` and`decodeURIComponent` doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using backslash("\") in the url it should be slash("/"). Ex. "/UserContent/fergers/102145860-Koala.jpg".

Comment: Ahh i see, i tryed to replace that aswell with 

var url = $(this).attr("src").replace("\\", "/"); but then he only changed the first one

Comment: Yep, `.replace()` only replaces the first occurrence. To replace all occurences, it is common to split+join like `"some\path\here".split('\').join('/')` - Even though these functions are intended for other uses, it does the replacement trick too.

Comment: Or replace does replace all if you use it properly! .replace(/\\/g,"/");